# Showing the inradius of a icosahedron with Paciolis construction.

Tags: geometry

This exercise is exercise 2.2.5 in the book "Mathematics and its history" (Stillwell):

Show that the center of triangle ABC is $\left(\frac{1}{3}(2\tau + 1), 0, \frac{\tau}{3}\right)$, and hence that the inradius $r$ is $\frac{1}{3}\sqrt{9\tau + 6}$ for this icosahedron. It follows that the circumradius $R$ to inradius $r$ ratio is $\frac{3\sqrt{\tau + 2}}{\sqrt{9\tau + 6}}$ for any icosahedron.

$\tau$ = $\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$ from the golden ratio.

For context, the triangle ABC is a same side triangle in Paciolis construction. The paciolis construction is a construction made of golden rectangles like the following:
[image]

I was wondering why my solution is incorrect:

For simplicity, I assume that the width of the rectangles is $2$ and the length is $2\tau$.

The coordinates for the triangle ABC are $A = (1, 0, \tau)$, $B = (\tau, -1, 0)$, and $C = (\tau, 1, 0)$.

To compute the center of $ABC$, I take the averages:

$G = \frac{1}{3} \left(2\tau + 1, 0, \tau\right)$

Using the distance formula, the difference between (0,0,0) and G is:
$\sqrt{\left(\frac{2\tau+1}{3}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\tau}{3}\right)^2}$ = $\sqrt{\frac{5r^2 + 4r + 1}{9}}$ which should be the inradius.

Comment: Please give context : e.g. what is $\tau$ ? How is triangle $ABC$ defined ? People reading this question don't have this book...

Comment: @JeanMarie Makes sense. I added more context.

Comment: Your calculation of the inradius is correct (except that your "$\tau$"s turned into "$r$"s at the end). Noticing that different radical expressions are equivalent can be tricky; but, with the golden ratio, there's a strategy: since $\tau^2=\tau+1$, you can always re-write any polynomial expression in $\tau$ as a *linear* expression in $\tau$. In your case, $$5\tau^2+4\tau+1=5(\tau+1)+4\tau+1=9\tau+6$$ so that your answer matches the target result.

Comment: Oh, thank you! Makes sense now.